# applicatoin not working in n73, working fine in N70!

Tags: symbian, n73

I have a problem in running the app in N73. I've tried that app in N70 and worked. Here in N73 it gets installed successfully, but when I open it, it just blink and goes off(Closed). even I can't find it in Background.

I built that app with the option Phone Release(GCCE) [S60_3rd_FP2_SDK_v1.1].

Any idea..!?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to track down what's the KernExec code being thrown. Carbide usually monitors the output log of the program, so you should be able to get the Exception id there.

You can have a look at the different meaning of symbian error codes here:
http://www.newlc.com/en/Symbian-OS-Error-Codes.html

I used to have an application you can install on your N73 that would popup a system dialog with the exception every time an application crashed however I can't quite remember what the name of it was so I guess carbide is your best option.

Try having a look at this:

http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/index.php/Crash_Analyser

Comment: Ya, thanks, But I have a problem. My application is working in my simulators and getting no errors. And I dont have facility to debug on the device directly.....

Comment: Then you definitively need to find the application that shows a dialog every time an exception occurs (sorry but I really can't remember what the name was). You can also try outputting log debug to a file and after the app crashes in the phone, read it.

Comment: Now I found the error code- " e32user-cbase 21 "
This error occurs only in N73. not in other s60 3rd edition phones.. I am wondering where I am wrong!!

Comment: It would seem you're overflowing some buffer. I could be the case that you are request for some feature that N73. Print debug to a file would be the next step. Create a debug panel to read the file.

`E32USER-CBase 21 - This panic is raised by any operation which accesses an element of an array by explicit reference to an index number, for example, the Delete(), InsertL() and At() member functions or the operator Operator[]. It is caused by specifying an index value which is either negative or is greater than or equal to the number of objects currently within the array.`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you download the excellent (and free) Y-Tasks application from http://www.drjukka.com/YTasks.html

Y-Tasks has a "Crash Monitor" module which displays information about whether a process exited normally, or whether it had to be "killed". It also displays the exit code (error code) returned by the process when it terminated.

Once you have the return code, (for example, "KERN-EXEC 3") you can refer to the documentation or the NewLC link posted by ruibm, for explanation of the error code. This should help you understand the problem.

For a quick and easy reference to the error codes, you can also use the "Panic Lookup" plugin for Carbide. (Google for it; as I'm a new user, I am only allowed to include 1 link per post.)